# When I update a panel with Ajax, do I need to set all events in that moment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm gonna show some pieces of my code. In my razor view, I've got a HTMLForm, and I want to use it with Ajax.

Look the following code for submit.

```
var editQuestionFormSubmit = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#target2').html(result);
            //$("#editQuestionForm").submit(editQuestionFormSubmit);
        }
    });
    return false;
};

var editQuestion = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "get",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#target2").html = result;
            $("#editQuestionForm").submit(editQuestionFormSubmit);
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

The `editQuestion` function is for the first time when the user does click in a hyperlink, with it the result contains a form and that's the reason why I've set it the submit event.

Now, when the user does the post, let's go to imagine that it's not validated, so I show again the same form but with the current model

```
    public ActionResult EditQuestion(QuestionTemplate qt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ....
           return ...
        }

        return PartialView("_EditQuestion", qt);
    }
```

So, the last code I return the same form but displaying the errors to validate and again I have to register the submit event handler. Am I doing a good approach or are there better ways to not register each event handler in each callback.

Answer (score 0):

Darf,

In the case of a `submit` event, handling cannot be delegated to an ancestor element because the event does not bubble. That denies you of the first choice approach to handling events arising from dynamically added elements.

So, with your approach to validation, you would have to attach the `submit` event handler each time the form is replaced.

However, you should be able to avoid the need to do so by replacing only the *contents* of the form (its `.html()`), leaving an original, hard-coded `<form>` element in place in the document.